# Multiple servers with a FileSystemWatcher on same directory

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems, filesystemwatcher

I would like to have the same service on multiple servers watching a single directory (on a shared server or SAN).  When a file appears in that directory I want one, and only one of those services to pick up that file and process its contents.

I attempted to program this by moving the file out of the shared directory before processing it.  I am fine with simply handling the exception on whichever server fails to move the file.  The problem is that conflicts occur and cause the file not to be processed by either server.

It is likely that files will arrive in batches, not one by one.  Does anyone know an approach to this that will work in a guaranteed way?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't provide a solution but I will say I have tried what you have said before using FSW and there are just too many issues going on (when dragging more than 20 files in from Win7 it doesnt pick them up, etc....). I ended up keeping a hashmap of filenames to access times and whatnot and used that to keep track of new/changed files (may seem kind of slow but rewritten in C it went much faster). This was my solution but it may not work for you which is why this is a comment instead (and a long one at that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try having one 'master' service with a FSW. The master service processes all FSW events and commands 'slave' services on remote machines to handle a certain file. Easy load balancing, no multiple FSW issues, no database needed. You could easily accomplish this with WCF.

Comment: I had thought of this myself but wanted to avoid it because preferably the servers run independantly and thus provide redundancy.  I guess I would just have to have a fail over configured for the master.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would have only one server/service monitoring that folder and writing in a database filepath and changed date and event (copy,rename...) then you can have all services you want to grab one of those recent new records in that table, lock it and processing it. Basically since FSW is working badly with concurrency we move concurrency handling to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the goal is to keep things out of the database at this stage - that introduces other issues.

Answer (score -1):

i will also suggest the solution form Davide Piras.
But if you still want to have the file watcher application in multiple servers looking for shared directory then one solution comes in mind is that you create the tcp connections between your file watcher application, as any file arrives in the shared dir then all file watcher applications generates random number and share that number with each other, then the application generated largest (or smallest) number should process that file. In this way only one file watcher application will process the file